# Node.js Mongoose modifying string data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Abstract**

Storing image data as a base64 encoded string works, but when viewing what is in Mongo the original string I saved is only about the first half of the ending persisted string.  Because of this querying does not work.

**Details**

Consider the following schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var imageSchema = new Schema({
    mime:  String,
    bin: String,
    uses : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);
```

In the `bin` field, I am storing base64 image data.  So this string can potentially be large (however this test fails when it is only about 40k as well).

**UPDATE**

I have done further analysis and this updated test block shows better the results I am seeing:

```
var buffer = getImageFromFileSystem();
var bin = buffer.toString('base64');
var i = new Image({
    mime : 'image/jpeg',
    bin : bin
});
i.save(function(err, image){
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    console.log("=== original? "+(image.bin === bin)); //outputs true
    console.log("now find it by id and then compare again")
    Image.findOne({
        _id : image._id
    }, function(err, img) {
        if (err)
            console.log('crap error');
        if (img) {
            console.log('found one!: '+img.id+', lets compare... ');
            console.log("===? "+(img.bin === bin)); //outputs true again!
        }
    });
    //OK so clearly all is well, so let search by the bin str
    Image.findOne({
        bin : bin
    }, function(err, img) {
        if (err)
            console.log('crap error');
        if (!img) {
            console.log("none found") // we hit this... what the heck???
    });
```

So I decide to go look in the database at the `bin` value.  *Here* is where I see that its value is my original `bin` String I saved plus at least twice as many characters appended to the end of it.  So my original base64 string is a substring at the beginning of the value stored in MongoDB.  So when I do `findOne({bin:myBinValue})` this doesn't work since the comparison is done inside Mongo.  However if I retrieve the `bin` value from Mongo and then compare, it seems to trim back to my original value and then in my application the javasript comparison is the same!  What gives!?  I have no indexes on this field.

```
> db.images.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "mydb.images",
                "name" : "_id_"
        }
]
```

Comment: The only limit on string length is the 16MB limit on a MongoDB doc.  But putting a `unique` index on `bin` isn't going to work as an indexed value must be less than 1024 bytes so maybe that's causing trouble.

Comment: I had also tried changing the `bin` property to just `bin : String` with the same result.  Am I missing something here?  Actually maybe is there a limitation on console.log?

Comment: You'd need to explicitly drop the index (in code or in the console), not just remove it from the schema.